# regex replace unable to substitute in Python with regex variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

we have huge number of files where we need to transfrom to json
here is the sampple data of one file

```
{
1=2,
4=tt,
6=9
}
{
1=gg,
2=bd,
6=bb
}
```

I am using python to convert the data where regex expression is working  fine but the same regex is  not working when i implementing in python code
here is the code

```
import numpy as np
f = open('/Users/rahulvarma/Downloads/2020120911.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
import re
regex = r"([0-9]+)(=)((.*)+)"
subst = "\"$1\":\"$3\","
result = re.sub(regex, subst, content,  0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

but my were

```
{
"$1":"$3",
"$1":"$3",
"$1":"$3"
}
{
"$1":"$3",
"$1":"$3",
"$1":"$3"
}
```

my expected output should be

```
{
"1":"2",
"4":"tt",
"6":"9"
}
{
"1":"gg",
"2":"bd",
"6":"bb"
}
```

Comment: You are not using Numpy for anything here; the `import` is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
(\d+)=([^,\n]*)(,|$)
```

And replace using:

```
"\1":"\2"\3
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nHtK76/1)

**Code:**

```
regex = r"(\d+)=([^,\n]*)(,|$)"

result = re.sub(regex, r'"\1":"\2"\3', input_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in captured group #1
- `=`: Match `=` character
- `([^,\n]*)`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `,` and not `\n` in captured group #2
- `(,|$)`: Match comma or end of line in captured group #3